# Golang rest API project structure

Tags: rest, go, architecture

I just started learning/using Golang, and want to develop a restful API (starting with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SonwZ6MF5BE&t=1346s) great video tutorial).

Do we have a best practice for the project structure for Golang projects? (such as [dropwizard's suggested project structure](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/manual/core.html#organizing-your-project) for java)

for example should I put the model (API request/response) in a separate directory? what is the suggested naming for API calls (equivalent to `resources` in dropwizard)? etc.

any suggestions/reference is appreciated

Comment: Questions about "best practices" are almost always purely opinion-based, and therefor off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I specifically mentioned the suggested project structure for Dropwizard - and looking equivalent structure for golang restAPI development. Clearly I'm looking to improve the code quality - which I don't think is off-topic

Comment: Improving code quality is an excellent goal, though "quality", like "best practice", is a nebulous and highly subjective topic, and therefor off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

For `rest-api` i use something like below,

```
.
├───app
│   ├───handlers
│   |───models
|   └───app.go
|───config
└───main.go
```

Where,

1. main.go - just pulls the config and bootstraps the api,
2. config - contains the configurations,
3. handlers - contains all the route handlers,
4. models - contains models to carry the data,
5. app.go - assembles the route with handlers

Answer (score -2):

A good structure for web applications I use is the following:

```
└───app
    ├───config
    ├───controllers
    └───models
```

I think its pretty straightforward to understand

Comment: Why do you need views folder if you build a REST API ?

Comment: @MounirOnGithub In our case, we might have certain transactional emails sent by the API which require a template (if you're not using a service for this).

Comment: Ok makes sense !